# How to iterate JSON objects with JSON objects in every object (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiple JSON objects which are have multiple JSON objects.
Now how do i iterate the Objects in deep.

My JSON structure is like below.

```
{
  "phanim": {
    "msg1": {
      "data": "Hii ra..",
      "date": "Sep 9",
      "sender": "Phani",
      "type": "text"
    },
    "msg2": {
      "data": "How r u?",
      "date": "Sep 9",
      "sender": "Phani",
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a recursive function - check if the `typeof` the current iterated property is an object, if so, iterate that!

```
var iterateObj = function(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            iterateObj(obj[key]);
        } else {
            console.log(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this won't work if one of your properties is an array - you'll need an additional check and logic for that.